# Volterra equation of first kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

**My given question:**

$x^2=\int_0^x \sin a (x-t)y(t)dt$ ; where $a\ne 0$

**My attempt:**
Knowing this is first kind Volterra, I make my way to second kind through differentiation, using Leibniz for the right:

$2x=\sin a \int_0^x y(t)dt$

Not really 2nd form, yet differentiation once more seems to find $y(x)$ inductively thinking. Using the idea of 'Fundamental Theorem of Calculus':

$2=y(x)\sin a $

hence,

$y(x)=\frac{2}{\sin a}$

My thought process sort of runs dry here.

Comment: Is it $$ \sin (a (x-t))$$ or $$(x-t) \sin a$$? You seem to be using the second option, but I suspect it should be the first one

Comment: No it was clarified to me that it's the 2nd one. They are separate terms

Comment: Then your solution is correct. I just checked it in my head. Why are you not sure?